# Using Open Sans family font in website

Tags: fonts, web-fonts

I want to implement the Open Sans font (a Google font) in a web site.

Can I use this font for free?
From what I read there is no problem to use it but I want to make sure it's OK.

Comment: Yes you can use it for free: https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Open+Sans

Answer (score 3):

It's free to use.

You can just add this to your HTML page:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

And then in your CSS:

```
p {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Open Sans is under the [Apache License](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html) and yes, you can use it for free.